# How to collect multiple LINQ results put into one variable as datasource of list view

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

How to collect multiple LINQ results and put into one as datasource of listview.
Here is my code.

```
for(int i=0;i<joinedSociety.length;i++)
{
    var joinSocietyRequest = from r in db.JoinSocietyRequests
                             where r.SocietyID.ToString() == manageSociety[i]
                             select new { r.User.Name, r.SocietyID,r.StudentID};

    if(joinSocietyReqeust != null)
        ?????>>>       
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean.  What do you *want* to do in that `if` block?

Comment: Sorry for ambiguous. For example, the for loop will loop 3 times and get 3 different results, how to put these 3 results into one as datasource of listview.

Comment: i should use List or DataTable or others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<dynamic> variable = new List<dynamic>();
```

Question solved after i declared this as listview datasource.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is you want.

Get rid of the for loop, just use something like:

```
var joinSocietyRequestList = (from r in db.JoinSocietyRequests
                     where manageSociety.Contains(r.SocietyID.ToString())    
                     select new
                     {
                        r.User.Name, 
                        r.SocietyID,
                        r.StudentID}).ToList();
```

Comment: so i need to declared a List first? like List <tableName> request = new List<tableName>();

But this come out structure error caused by i get User Name from other table.